# How to make a button redirect to another page in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component which has in its `Class.propTypes` a function onClick: `onClick: PropTypes.func`

In another component I'm using this component multiple times to populate a page. Each of these components have a title which when clicked should redirect to another page.

The problem I have is that it doesn't work when I click on it. It does nothing.
This is the render of the main component:

```
render() {
    return (
            <Class
    title={account.AccountName}
    onClick={() => "mySite/accountview?id=" + account.AccountName} 
         >
         </Class>
          ...
    );
}
```

What should I add to `onClick` to make it work?

Comment: is the page you want to go to within the same React App or an external website? Are you using some kind of routing library, such as [tag:react-router]?

Comment: same React App, I'm not using routing library. `accountview` is the name of that component

Comment: Then I suggest you install [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) first and add your pages to the router.

Comment: I guess it will be too difficult to do that. The project is pretty big and also has parts and pages written in vb.net and other languages

Comment: But you said those other pages are in react as well?

Comment: The one I want to redirect to it is in react but there are others which are not

Comment: In that case I would still add react-router and use Gabriels solution below. The former for navigating within the react app, and the latter for external sites.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147275/discussion-between-user3654571-and-chris).

Answer (score 3):

You need use [React Router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router).

With `Link`:

```
<Link to={`/mySite/accountview?id=${account.AccountName}`}>something</Link>
```

With `onClick`:

```
<button onClick={() => hashHistory.push(`/mySite/accountview?id=${account.AccountName}`)}></button>
```

You can use `hashHistory` or `browserHistory` :D

Comment: Use browserHistory for clean urls. ;)

Comment: Hi Gabriel, should i use window.location="url path mentioned in Link Tag"  in my button click function inorder to route to the url path mentioned in Link Tag